# Streaming images with Yesod and any image conversion library

Tags: haskell, image-processing, streaming, yesod

I need to work with tiff images online. Tiff images are not supported by browsers. So i thought maybe  i can convert them on the fly and stream them into the browser as pngs.

I found many image processing haskell libraries and JuicyPixels looks simple enough and supports reading from tiff and saving to many other formats including png.

The simplest case is to just save to png file and then serve it with sendFile

But i think involving hard drive in the process is going to add too much overhead and substantially slow down the response. SO my question is, how do i stream the image converted with JuicyPixels from tiff to png directly, without saving it into a file first.

Does JuicyPixels have any streaming interfaces? Or maybe there's a simple enough way to get to data representation in specific format and then pass it to any streaming libraries like conduit?

As i side question, anyone did streaming images from Yesod?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with JuicyPixels, but it looks like it encodes to lazy ByteStrings. If that's the case, then you just need to return that lazy ByteString wrapped up in a [`DontFullyEvaluate`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-core/Yesod-Core-Types.html#t%3aDontFullyEvaluate).